# Test a string vs current_url in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Using `Python 3.4` and `Selenium`

I'm trying to test the current webpage vs a string. So for example:

```
while(webdriver.current_url == "https://www.youtube.com/"):
         print("sleep")
         time.sleep(5)
```

However, this does not work. I've tried printing out the links and just copying and pasting it to the string portion of my check, but that doesn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My guess is that `webdriver.current_url` does not return a string, but I've encased it in `str()` in python and that still doesn't work. I've also tried making the `current_url` smaller, by doing `current_url[1:-1]` and so on, that hasn't helped so I'm not sure what other things I can try.

Comment: you haven't displayed all of your code, so it's not possible to tell exactly what is happening.  You also haven't defined what "does not work" means or if error output is displayed.  See my answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `python 3.4`, the code you shared is working for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.current_url, type(driver.current_url), type("https://www.youtube.com/"))
while(driver.current_url == "https://www.youtube.com/"):
    print("sleep")
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

Add the following line for debugging purpose before `while` loop:

```
print webdriver.current_url, type(webdriver.current_url) # prints types as 'unicode' for me, but still code is working fine. tried with python 2.7
while(webdriver.current_url == "https://www.youtube.com/"):
     print("sleep")
     time.sleep(5)
```

Suggest to check what the value is being returned by `webdriver.current_url`

Answer (score 0):

YouTube might be stripping the trailing `/` or adding query string parameters automatically after you navigate to the URL. Try:

```
while('https://www.youtube.com' in webdriver.current_url):
```

Comment: it doesn't strip it

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver` is the name of the python module you should have imported with: `from selenium import webdriver`.  Therefore, it wouldn't even have a `current_url` property.

did you mean something like this?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
if driver.current_url == "https://www.youtube.com/":
    print('look, they are equal')
```

(notice I am getting the value of `current_url` from the `webdriver.Chrome` instance I create)